# jQuery DataPicker doesn't work MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datapicker

I found jQuery DataPicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#slider_examples).
But it doesn't work. I tried test it in this way:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="basic_example_1" id="basic_example_1" value="" class="hasDatepicker">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

I heard that I should check console for errors. However I'm beginner and I've no idea where is the console in Chrome? Can anyone show me (screenshot)?

By the way - source:
jqueryui.com/download/ and
https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/tree/master/dist

Comment: To open console in chrome press cntr+Shift+C

Comment: http://prntscr.com/92utpc it looks empty... :(

Comment: did you try upgrading jquery to version 1.11.1?